# MongoDB 6 sharding split by collection

Tags: mongodb

This is for a school project and I am having some dificultiys understading the shared keys.

This is my setup:
3 Machines each having 1 consif server node, 1 shard1 node, 1 shard2 node. and then just for testing one of this machines have the router.

I have this working fine, I think :P

Now on this I have a database that will have 2 collections and with the following fields:
se_temp:
InsertDate , Reading, SensorID (this will have between 1 to 3 max sensor ids)
se_door:
InsertDate, From, To -> the from and to value will have values between 1 and 10

What I am trying to achieve with no sucess is to have each collection to each shard if this is possible.

Also to note most of the querys that the application performes is based on the InsertDate.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
edit to add the sh.status() output
shardingVersion
{
  _id: 1,
  minCompatibleVersion: 5,
  currentVersion: 6,
  clusterId: ObjectId("647216f9180976b065bb2686")
}
---
shards
[
  {
    _id: 'shard1ReplSet',
    host: 'shard1ReplSet/X.X.X.X:27013,X.X.X.X:27011,X.X.X.X:27012',
    state: 1,
    topologyTime: Timestamp({ t: 1685198765, i: 3 })
  },
  {
    _id: 'shard2ReplSet',
    host: 'shard2ReplSet/X.X.X.X:27023,X.X.X.X:27021,X.X.X.X:27022',
    state: 1,
    topologyTime: Timestamp({ t: 1685198770, i: 3 })
  }
]
---
most recently active mongoses
[ { '6.0.4': 1 } ]
---
autosplit
{ 'Currently enabled': 'yes' }
---
balancer
{
  'Currently running': 'yes',
  'Currently enabled': 'yes',
  'Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts': 0,
  'Migration Results for the last 24 hours': 'No recent migrations'
}
---
databases
[
  {
    database: { _id: 'config', primary: 'config', partitioned: true },
    collections: {
      'config.system.sessions': {
        shardKey: { _id: 1 },
        unique: false,
        balancing: true,
        chunkMetadata: [ { shard: 'shard1ReplSet', nChunks: 1024 } ],
        chunks: [
          'too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print'
        ],
        tags: []
      }
    }
  },
  {
    database: {
      _id: 'pisidg23',
      primary: 'shard2ReplSet',
      partitioned: false,
      version: {
        uuid: new UUID("ce24dbdb-8eaf-4b83-9103-6636590e6efd"),
        timestamp: Timestamp({ t: 1685198773, i: 1 }),
        lastMod: 1
      }
    },
    collections: {}
  }
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure how we can begin to answer the question given the information provided. What is your logical sharding configuration within the cluster (eg the output of `sh.status()`)? This also feels like a question better fit for dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @user20042973 I am a bit lost on this.. my data is to simplistic and not sure the best wahy to do the sarding. For example the se_temp I can have multiple entrys for the same sensorID but I have like 1 to 3 sensores IDs that will appear and it will have multiple entrys for the same id. Something happens for the other collection. and I can't change this information

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot select different primary shards per collection, but if your collections are in different databases then - yes , you can [move](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/movePrimary/#moveprimary) the primary database shard in different shard per each database.
2. You need to choose the shard key index very carefully since the queries you send to your collection if not part of shard key will be send to all shards. If you dont use often your index in queries better choose different index for shard key.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can only use one database and I don't controll the data that is send to the collections.

I am having dificulty to choose the shard key. 98% of my querys are based on the insertDate, that we shouldn't used the date as the key, but just for simplicity and disscution with my professor should I use, for example the sendorID in the collection for se_temp? this is ID can have mutiple entrys